# How to flatten a 2 deep list, return a list without any sublists within

Tags: python, list, flatten

I was working on an algorithm that 'flattens' a list, essentially removing any sublists within a list.

For example, [2, 3, [3, 4]] should become [2, 3, 3, 4]. I wrote the following to do this:

```
def flatten(l):
    total = []
    for i in l:
       if i == int:
           total.append(i)
       elif i == list:
           for j in i:
               total.append(j):
    return total
```

This algorithm yields an error, however. If someone could help that would be great. Also, if someone could show a recursive path to solve this problem so that lists of arbitrary 'depth' can be flattened (my current algorithm can only flatten a 2D array)

Comment: This algorithm yields an error, however. If someone could help that would be great. Also, if someone could show a recursive path to solve this problem so that lists of arbitrary 'depth' can be flattened (my current algorithm can only flatten a 2D array)

Comment: Use `isinstance(i,int)`, if list append each, else append

Comment: Use `isinstance` instead of `==`.

Comment: here's the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: @keda that's not the answer, since this is not a list of lists. This just *has* some lists in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)

Comment: This is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: @anishtain4 read my above comment to keda.

Comment: So the question looks exactly the same as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major issues here - first, you aren't checking the type of the item correctly (you should use `isinstace`) and second you aren't calling the function recursively:

```
def flatten(l):
    total = []
    for i in l:
       if isinstance(i, list):
           total.extend(flatten(i))       
       else:
           total.append(i)

    return total
```