# i want to Make one list from list of list python with some condition i mentioned the expected output

Tags: python

I have a list of list i want to merge them in to one with ''

```
associated_values=[['chennai'], ['printer', 'pc', 'notebook']]
```

i want this output

```
["chennai","'printer','pc','notebook'"]
```

this code is not working.  i want two list as two comma separated string values same as the required output.

```
 for i in associated_values:
        s=''
        newlist.append(str(s.join(i)))
```

Comment: That's because the items are lists and not strings.

Comment: yes i know, how can i get the required output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flatten a 2 deep list, return a list without any sublists within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820962/how-to-flatten-a-2-deep-list-return-a-list-without-any-sublists-within)

Comment: Answered your question @mayankchauhan

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```py
associated_values=[['chennai'], ['printer', 'pc', 'notebook']]
newlist = []
for i in associated_values:
    if len(i) == 1:
        newlist.append("'"+str(i[0]+"'"))
    else:
        s = ''
        for item in i:
            if item != i[0]:
                s += ' ,' + "'"+str(item)+ "'"
            else:
                s += "'"+str(item)+"'"
        newlist.append(s)
print(newlist)
```

**Output**

```py
============================== RESTART: D:\x.py ==============================
["'chennai'", "'printer' ,'pc' ,'notebook'"]
>>>
```

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: Sir, this is what i want   ["chennai"," 'printer','pc' ,'notebook' "]    values should be in 'quotes' in second list

Comment: @mayankchauhan did it help?

Answer (score -1):

The following should give you what you want :

```
for e in associated_values:
    newlist.append(str(e)[1:-1])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can solve your problem using this approach:

```
associated_values=[['chennai'], ['printer', 'pc', 'notebook']]
result = list(map(lambda x: ','.join(map(lambda y: "'" + y + "'" if len(x) > 1 else y, x)), associated_values))
print(result)
# ['chennai', "'printer','pc','notebook'"]
```

Answer (score -2):

If you wand output as a list you can use this :

```
associated_values=[['chennai'], ['printer', 'pc', 'notebook']]

newlist = []

for i in associated_values:
    for _ in i:
        newlist.append(_)


print(newlist)

# Output : ['chennai', 'printer', 'pc', 'notebook']
```